# How to properly setup a MYSQL database with JAVAFX intellij?

Tags: mysql, database, intellij-idea, javafx

Ok so Im am still very new to javafx and intellij. I am working on a little project of my own right now and all I am trying to build is a simple calendar just like apple's version or google's. I figured this would be a good exercise for me to get to know the Intellij IDE better and JavaFX.

Here is the problem that I seem to be stuck with for a couple days now. In my application, a user has the ability to create a new event which contains many properties such as "event name", "first name", "last name" etc.. Now all the information is stored in a shall we call it "NewEvent" Node. Here lies the problem I am facing. I am trying to save the data locally on the clients computer however I am not sure how to begin. I have browsed around and I have found this thing called MYSQL that is supposed to do just that. I was hoping you guys could help me out here on how I should set this up.

Here is what I've done so far.

1. Downloaded MYSQL v5.7
2. Downloaded MYSQLWorkbench
3. Created a Database called "event" with all the properties contained in the Node
4. Somehow added the MYSQL database to intellij
5. Created a dialog where if the user clicks save, all the information is stored in a node.

To my understanding in order to access the data stored in the MYSQL table, shouldnt the "data file" be saved in my project folder? I have no clue where this is located. Also how would I gain access to database in order to edit it dynamically. Like adding a new row to the database.

I have looked up online with many different searches but they all seem to be using NetBeans and they are mostly outdated. I found it really hard to find information from start to finish. All I want to do is to store data locally and to access it. I expect to have a largely populated database, seeing as no one actually deletes an event once its over so what I was told is that MYSQL is capable of handling huge data. Hence my choice to go along with it.

I have done a little Android Application last summer so I am a little familiar with MYSQL, however I remember saving the data onto a table on the clients phone.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't an embedded database. Only the [libmysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld.html) is embeddable.

You can integrate JavaFx application with any database. HSQLDB or H2 would be more appropriate, since they do not need an installation on the client machine, and can be configured to save the data file on any location.